# Will charge transfer without friction

Tags: electrostatics, friction, charge, conductors, insulators

I know rubbing two objects of different materials together will result in a negative charge on whichever material has a higher electron affinity. However, I was wondering if a negatively charged conductor (which has low electron affinity) and a neutral insulator are touching, will electrons move to the insulator over time (no friction between them)? I know there would be a potential difference since the conductor is negatively charged, so would that be enough to make the electrons move? Or does there absolutely need to be friction?

Comment: Move any object along another object in normal conditions and you will always get some friction, even a small amount.

Comment: I can easily transfer charge from one object to another without friction. For example, I can make an electron beam and spray it onto objects.  So, while I don't think that answers your question, I would say that your question is not as well formed and stated as you might like to get good answers.

Comment: I meant exactly what I said. If you have a negatively charged conductor (say copper), and a neutral insulator (plastic for example), will charge move from the conductor to the insulator? Assume there is no movement between the two (so then no kinetic friction).

Comment: Although the part 'tribo-' comes from the Greek for "rubbing", τρίβω (τριβή: friction), the two materials only need to come into contact and then separate for electrons to be exchanged.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect#Cause

Answer (score -2):

FIRSTLY, INSULATED OBJECT CANNOT LET THE CURRENT TO SURPASS SO NEITHER THE CHARGE IS ACCUMULATED. BUT IF U SAY A NEUTRAL BODY THEN THE CASE IS APART i.e different.  SO IF U SAY A NEUTRAL BODY THEN YES ELECTRONS GET MOVED DURING INDUCTION AS ELECTRONS WEIGHT LESSER THAN PROTONS SO COMPELLING ELECTRONS TO MOVE DURING INDUCTION GRADUALLY TAKES PLACE.. BY THIS I MEAN U DON'T NEED FRICTION PARTICULARLY.

```
            I WOULD BE GLAD FOR ANY FEED BACKS.
```

Comment: Writing all text in full caps is NOT cool. Please read [Being nice](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) WRITING IN CAPSLOOK ALWAYS SEEMS AGGRESSIVE, so we try to avoid that. You might also take the tour: http://physics.stackexchange.com/tour and see the helpcentre http://physics.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: This answer is unclear, aggressive, and the request for feed back makes it seem speculative. It needs to be clarified and specific scientific concepts should be referred to, at least